# Desktop wall paper goes black, desktop is almost in accessible

Tags: unity

I am not sure if installing Cinnamon desktop is causing the issue. But desktop wall paper becomes black,and system hangs(no such issue in W7 64 bit).

Even from launcher some open application goes to the black hole. I have Ubuntu tweak and in Unity settings, I got the error posted below.

Please let me know how to uninstall Cinnamon desktop on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit.

**Error code** :

```
" 
Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 precise
Application: Ubuntu Tweak 0.6.0-1~oneiric1
Desktop:ubuntu

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/main.py", line 444, in _load_module
    page = module()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/tweaks/unity.py", line 69, in __init__
    enable_reset=True),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/factory.py", line 46, in create
    return getattr(cls, 'do_composite_create')(widget, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/factory.py", line 59, in do_composite_create
    new_widget = globals().get(widget)(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/gui/widgets.py", line 207, in __init__
    self._setting = CompizSetting(key=key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/compizsettings.py", line 69, in __init__
    self._setting = self._plugin.create_setting(setting_name, target)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/compizsettings.py", line 58, in create_setting
    return settings[key]
KeyError: 'launcher_reveal_edge_timeout' "
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried both commands without success. First one says there is not service called gdm. Most programs do not launch if I click the icon on Unity bar. Ubuntu is almost unusable. Just for gamble, could you please give me the command to u uninstall Cinnamon.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Ubuntu tweak

check [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+bug/926420) on launchpad

This bug is solved in version 0.6.1.

If you want to use it, try the testing

> ppa: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-tweak-testing/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

Or

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```